# Cómo cambiar color de fondo de un div desde un dato de una tabla en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla donde hay una columna llamada `color_semaforo` donde se manejan solo 3 tipos de valores 0, 1 y 2:

0 = verde, 1 = ambar, 2 = rojo

Lo que quiero hacer es que al realizar mi consulta y mostrar los datos en mi tabla html la columna que lleva por nombre semaforo y contiene un div su `bg-color` sea acuerdo al valor, es decir si ese dato tiene en `color_semaforo` 0 se pinte de verde, según sea en cada caso.

esta es la tabla donde dice semaforo quiero cambiar los colores del div de acuerdo a su valor

[image: Tabla que muestro en el index]

```
 <tbody>
              <?php
              foreach ($rows as $row ) {
               ?>
                <tr>
                   <td>
                      <?php echo $row['proyecto']; ?>
                    </td>
                      <td class="project_progress">
                      <div class="progress progress_sm">
                        <div class="progress-bar bg-green" role="progressbar" data-transitiongoal="100"></div>
                      </div>
                      <small><a href="#">Ver Detalle</a></small>
                    </td>
                    <td class="project_progress">
                      <div class="progress progress_sm">
                        <div class="progress-bar bg-blue role="progressbar" data-transitiongoal="60"></div>
                      </div>
                      <small>60% de Avance </small>
                    </td>
                   <td>
                      <a><?php echo $row['empresa'];?></a>
                      <br />
                    </td>
                       <td>
                      <a><?php echo $row['origen'];?></a>
                      <br />
                    </td>
                       <td>
                      <a><?php echo $row['ubicacion'];?></a>
                      <br />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <a><?php echo $row['municipio'];?></a>
                      <br />
                    </td>
                     <td>
                      <a><?php echo $row['sector'];?></a>
                      <br />
                    </td>
                     <td>
                      <a><?php echo $row['inversion'];?></a>
                      <br />
                    </td>
                     <td>
                      <a><?php echo $row['empleos'];?></a>
                      <br />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <a><?php echo $row['dependencia'];?></a>
                      <br />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <a><?php echo $row['giro'];?></a>
                      <br />
                    </td>
                     <td>
                      <a><?php echo $row['nombre'];?></a>
                      <br />
                       <small><a href="#">Ver Información del Contacto</a></small>
                    </td>


                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
              </tbody>
```

Esa es la parte del codigo donde llamo al div, intente hacerlo con un script pero no logre resolverlo.

Comment: podrias poner la estructura de la tabla? o algun codigo

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el código que has intentado hasta ahora, y explicarnos donde estás teniendo dificultad? No creo que tu intención sea que alguien haga todo el trabajo por ti.

Comment: Si colocas algo de código, podremos responderte adecuadamente.

Comment: Ya subi un poco de como esta estructurada mi tabla+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La idea es esta: haces una consulta a tu tabla y obtienes el valor (0, 1 o 2). Luego creas una clase css donde:

```
.cero{
  background.color: yellow;
}

.uno{
  background.color: red;
}

.dos{
  background.color: green;
}
```

Entonces, haces una condición de tu consulta donde:

```
if ($res == 0){
  $clase = 'cero';
}elseif ($res == 1){
  $clase = 'uno';
}else{
  $clase = 'dos';
}
```

Y por último imprimes ese valor donde quieras en el html:

```
<div class=<? echo $clase; ?>
```

Ya que no colocas nada de código, no puedo darte algo ya hecho para que copies y pegues. Pero esto debe bastar para que lo puedas hacer con éxito.

Comment: Ya entendi tu ida amigo, creo que haci le voy a hacer. Gracias!!